# How to quickly find elements in a sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, ldap

I am new here but have checked previous posts about this and although similiar, not quite enough for what I'm trying to do.  I have a CSV file with 40K+ records and retrieve LDAP records of 70K+ records; both stored in multidimensional array variable. The objective is to display all records that DO NOT match. My current solution is taking over 20 minutes to process which is inefficient.  I created an outer loop that for each record it checks for a match in the LDAP recordset (inner loop), if found skip to next record and unset the LDAP array index to shrink the array for the next loop. I have also sorted both arrays in ascending order to speed up the process.  Ideas, tweaks, help to speed up process?

```
foreach($csvArray as $csvindex=>$csvalue) { 
echo "<br />csvArray record: <strong> ".$counter."</strong><br />\n";

  if($counter <= 1) {

      for ($i = 0, $max=$rs["count"]-1; $i < $max ;$i++) { //loop through ldap array
            if($csvalue[0] == $rs[$i]['uid'][0]) { // csv netid & ldap netid
                echo "CSV netid: ".$csvalue[0];
                echo "<br />matched LDAP array [$i] netid: ".$rs[$i]["uid"][0];
                echo "<br />\n";
                $matched = $i; //$i represents integer offset in array (ie. $rs[21])
                break;
            }
      }

    } else {

    unset($rs[$matched]); //remove matched items
    $newRS = array_values($rs); //re-indexes array

    echo "Size of new LDAP array: ".count($newRS);

      for ($i=0, $max=count($newRS); $i<$max; $i++) {
          if($csvalue[0] == $newRS[$i]['uid'][0]) { // csv netid & ldap netid
            echo "<br />CSV netid: ".$csvalue[0];
            echo "<br />matched LDAP array [$i] netid: ".$newRS[$i]["uid"][0];
            echo "<br />\n";
            $matched = $i; //$i represents integer offset in array (ie. $rs[21])
            break;
          }
      }

    } 

$counter++;
}
```

Example of what the original arrays look like (some info changed for security):

```
 //csvArray 
 Array (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => ABABABAB
        [1] => test.account
        [2] => Chad
        [3] => Moeller
        [4] => chad.moeller@macmillan.com
        [5] => 9/10/2013 9:29 AM
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => D2L1.Test
        [1] => w40
        [2] => D2L 
        [3] => Test
        [4] => 
        [5] => 10/28/2013 4:24 PM
    )

//ldap multidimensional array
Array (
[count] => 67
[0] => Array
    (
        [uid] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [0] => alackey1
            )

        [0] => uid
        [count] => 1
        [dn] => uid=alackey1,dc=edu
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [uid] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [0] => blamb3
            )

        [0] => uid
        [count] => 1
        [dn] => uid=blamb3,dc=edu
    )
```

Comment: Instead of a straight array for the LDAP records, you might consider a tree (binary or otherwise). The inefficiency you're experiencing is due to starting at the beginning of the LDAP list each time. With a binary tree you can make the max number of LDAP records you have to check on the order of log2(n). And if you remove nodes from the LDAP tree as you go, that would help some also. I don't think you'd get much of a performance hit either since you're currently going through the process of sorting the LDAP records. Just replace that sort with loading the tree.

Comment: With 70k records, the max number of records to check in the LDAP tree would be 17.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am not familiar with LDAP tree(s).  If you could point me to a reference or example it would be a big help.  I also want to minimize the amount of ldap calls if possible. Thanks!

Comment: With your current sorted list of LDAP records, you could also just do a binary search. Compare first to the middle record. If less than middle record, your next LDAP working list is the first half of the LDAP array. Then, again, compare to the middle record. Repeat until you find or working array length = 0. This approach is actually simpler than using a tree. It's doing what you're doing now, but not starting at the beginning each time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of code to replace your inner loop. It uses a binary search. The LDAP array must be sorted before this point.

```
$workingArray=$newRS;
while($LDAPcount=count($workingArray)) {
    $indexToCheck=ceil($LDAPcount/2);
    if($csvalue[0] == $workingArray[$indexToCheck]['uid'][0]) { // csv netid & ldap netid
        echo "<br />CSV netid: ".$csvalue[0];
        echo "<br />matched LDAP array ".$workingArray[$indexToCheck]["uid"][0];
        echo "<br />\n";
        $matched = $indexToCheck; //$indexToCheck represents integer offset in array (ie. $rs[21])
        break;
    } else {
        if($csvalue[0] < $workingArray[$indexToCheck]['uid'][0]) {
            $workingArray=array_slice($workingArray,0,$indextoCheck);
        } else {
            $workingArray=array_slice($workingArray,$indextoCheck+1);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Great, Thank You! I am not a CS major, so I am wrapping my brain around the algorithm first. Looks like it'll work well. I will give this a shot and comment later. Note, this reference says array_slice is inefficient http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Search/Binary_search#PHP.

Comment: `array_slice` itself is not inefficient, but the wikibooks reference is correct in that the use of slice for this purpose is inefficient. They give a better algorithm using two variables to keep track of the "top" and "bottom" of the desired array section. Their version is pretty good.